# Stellar winds from neutron stars

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics, neutron-stars, stellar-wind

It seems that this question has not really been explored in the literature. Do isolated neutron stars (which do not accrete material) emit stellar wind? If yes, what composition would it have? If yes, what will be the rate of mass loss for the star?

One might also think up that the process of Hawking radiation might possibly be applicable to neutron stars, where negative energy particles get trapped in the nuclear star atmosphere (instead of crossing the horizon in case of black holes), which would also lead to some sort of evaporation and corresponding wind. However, in this question I am more interested in 'classical' winds.

Comment: Neutron stars are really complex objects that have a lot of dynamics to their constituent parts, and very large magnetic fields.  I expect that the answer to your question is going to be a "probably, but it depends on a lot of things."  I would also expect there to be no quantum Hawking-style radiation, as the magnitude of that effect is governed by the black hole horizon's area, which is zero for a neutron star.

Comment: I suspect the answer is probably "no" for a naked neutron star. If the star retains an envelope from earlier in its evolution it might still be able to fuel a wind. With just the star, though, I think the essentially solid nature of the stellar surface would prevent a sustained wind. Unfortunately I can't find any references to back up my intuition...

Comment: Dear @JerrySchirmer, concerning neutron stars, they surely exhibit great diversity, they also evolve (cool down), may be in accreting binary, have an envelope of remnants, etc. Still, it would be interesting to know the magnitude of the most typical mass loss rates for most typical isolated neutron stars. Concerning Hawking radiation, the key thing for it is not an event horizon, but a "membrane" surface, which lets everything go one way only. As neutron stars are very opaque, I could imagine easily particles getting stuck in their atmosphere, as if behind a membrane.

Comment: Dear @Kyle, the word solid might be misleading. Surely, the densities of matter are extreme. However, the structure of the atmosphere is not crystalline, as is the case for the solids we are used to. Instead, it is dense gas-like matter, and even though the scale height of an atmosphere is very small, the transition between the star and the vacuum is smooth, and the density (and pressure) drops to zero continuously. This resembles atmospheres of real stars, except for that here they are tremendously compressed and have rather exotic state of matter.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick: what you describe is a trapping horizon, and nuetron stars don't have them.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: Imagine a very sticky very sharp (accelerated) wall. It shall work in a perfectly similar way to an event horizon of a black hole.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick: you're not understanding how Hawking Radiation is generated.  The mechanism is from incompatible time coordinates creating different notions of vacuum, causing one observer to see particles where the other doesn't.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick I'm not a NS expert, but my understanding is that they have some solid properties. In particular, I think thermonuclear bursts in accreting NSs are understood in the context of a solid crust. I don't disagree that there are some gas-like properties, but I wouldn't call it a "gas" (nor would I call it a "solid").

Comment: @Kyle The bulk material is generally described as a "degenerate gas", but that should not be confused with a diffuse gas of the sorts we encounter on Earth.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer, The same applies to the wall example. Consider an inertial observer and the one, which is accelerated together with the wall: both will have different comoving coordinates, and different local vacuum. So your last argument is not valid.

Comment: @Kyle, thanks! Would you agree, still, that thermodynamic properties of the star, such as pressure and density, fall off to zero continuosly and on the scales larger than atomic ones?

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick: something special happens at the horizon, though--you get an infinite blueshifting of incoming wavelets relative to conformal infinity.

Comment: @Jerry, this is true, but I don't think it is relevant (can you prove the opposite?). For example, a static observer, which is located near the black hole (not in the infinity) will also observe Hawking radiation.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick: i've seen the derivation of hawking radiation, which depends intimately on the existence of a horizon.  I don't know of a realistic exact solution of Einstein's equation that corresponds to a NS that I could use to repeat this derivation.  A static observer near the black hole will still observe infinite blueshifting at the horizon.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer, you are right of course about the infinite blueshift (mind my previous post). Yet, my claim is that the role of the event horizon is to be a membrane, and that is why it is important in the derivation.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick: point me to a quantitative derivation of the entropy formula where this is the case and show me how that would generalize to a neutron star, even in principle.  I will refer you to Hawking's original paper which makes explicit use of the horizon for the blueshift phenomenon.

Comment: Dear @JerrySchirmer, so far I have found a simple argument against my idea actually. Namely, if neutron stars were to radiate this way, where would the radiated energy come from? Your argument, as I said, doesn't prove yet, that the event horizon in necessary for evaporation. If I find a satisfactory resolution to the problem with the mass of the star, I shall post all this as a separate question with some key points of our discussion (if you don't object).

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick: I don't object.  But all I say is that the event horizon and the blueshifting at it is essential to deriving Hawking radiation in the black hole case.  And absent a model of the neutron star interior, you're going to have trouble coming up with a clean derivation here, without a clear reason why.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer, neutron star interior would be not so important to model. I would be happy enough to have it proved/disproved for any static opaque sphere with any equation of state.

Answer (score 5):

I don't claim to be an expert on this topic, but I found this recent review paper: [arXiv:1211.0852](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0852). Here's a short summary covering the questions above.

Isolated neutron stars can emit a wind powered by the rotational energy of the star. As it slows, it loses energy at a rate $\dot{E} = 4\pi^2I\dot{P}/P^3$ where $E$ is the rotational kinetic energy of the star, $P$ is its rotational period, $I$ is its moment of inertia and a dot denotes a time derivative. This energy loss can drive a relativistic wind of electrons and positrons, which is visible via synchrotron radiation from the interaction of the wind particles with the (often very strong!) local magnetic field. Whether all neutron stars DO emit a wind is as yet unknown.

87 out of 103 galactic objects (at least tentatively) identified as neutron stars have an associated detection showing or suggesting a wind. These are primarily stars not in binary systems, but instead discovered in supernova remnants.

As to Hawking radiation, my understanding is that the process requires an event horizon to occur, but maybe someone with a better understanding of that process can weight in.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference! Though the article is non-refereed, it has a number of references therein. My impression is that they talk mainly about newly born and/or highly magnetised pulsars, focusing on the effect of those on the interstellar medium. Young pulsars apriori emit a lot (especially, neutrinos), as they are very hot. For example, two references (the text, section about winds) Pacini & Salvati (1973), and Rees & Gunn (1974) discuss Crab pulsar (very young one).

Comment: Further, Pacini (1967)‡, Gold (1968) suggest two other mechanisms for the neutron stars to emit energy: 1) Dipole emission, 2) Strong magnetic field drags the ambient plasma to corotate with the neutron star, which will accelerate it to ultrarelativistic speeds. The latter possibility is not a wind from the neutron star precisely speaking, but looks very interesting. In the end the article leaves it as a question, if winds from neutron stars can power pulsar wind nebulae, found around the most magnetised pulsars. Yet, one can see from Fig 1, nuetron stars in the article are not very typical.

Answer (score 5):

Young neutron stars and the winds they energize, lay cause to some of the most extreme
physical environments in the universe. The exact plasma and wind production
mechanism are not well understood, but the basic picture is as follows.

At the stellar surface, the pulsar’s huge magnetic fields and rapid rotation induce
enormous electric fields within the magnetosphere, these consequently tear particles
from the stellar surface and accelerate them to high energies. Plasma then fills
the magnetosphere and the extreme magnetic field present is sufficient to cause
the plasma to rigidly co-rotate. However, this co-rotation must cease somewhere
near the light cylinder, and the particles flow along the opened magnetic field lines,
carrying away energy in the form of an ultrarelativistic magnetized wind.

In those cases, where the conditions are conducive to the formation of a rapidly rotating
neutron star, a pulsar wind, driven by the pulsar spin-down power *is likely* to *always* be formed.

> If yes, what composition would it have? If yes, what will be the rate of mass loss for the star?

The first of the above questions depends on the angle that the axis of the stars magnetic field makes with its rotational axis. In reality, pulsars will almost always be oblique rotators (with $\mathbf{B}$ miss-aligned to the axis of rotation). In this case the wind from the star will take the form of a [*striped wind*](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0306435). However, most mathematical models of pulsars assume and aligned rotator and instead of modelling this stripped wind explicitly they do this implicitly - this avoids 3D models and a massive increase in complexity.

The rate of mass loss due to such a wind is something that we do not know for sure. However, it is likely to be directly ascociated with the spin-down power of the star - but again, depending on the 'obliqeness' of the rotation, this will vary.

> One might also think up that the process of Hawking radiation might possibly be applicable to neutron stars...

I know of no reason to suggest that Hawking Radiation would act in the way you have suggested. This mechanism is purely associated with event horizons. However, one mechanism associated predominantly with black-holes and that *may* have some bearing for pulsars is the Blandford–Znajek process. This is a mechanism for the extraction of energy from a rotating black hole. It is one of the best explanations for the way quasars are powered. It requires an accretion disc with a strong polar magnetic field around a spinning black hole. The magnetic field extracts spin energy and the power can be estimated as the energy density at the speed of light cylinder. I have never seen suggestion of this process being applicable to neutron stars, but I have not looked - to me it would be a far more likely mechanism...

I hope this helps.